# Unable to make Telerik dropdownlist read-only

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I am trying to make a Kendo dropdownlist read-only via Javascript based on a boolean. I've been looking through various tutorials and stackoverflow questions but have yet to get something to help me. Here is what I have so far:

dropdownlist:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("ddlConsultantCompany")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px;" })
          .DataTextField("CompanyName")
          .DataValueField("CompanyId")
          .Value(Model.Consultant.CompanyID.ToString())
          .DataSource(source =>
                      source.Read(read =>
                                  read.Action("GetCompanies", "DropDown")))
)
```

Javascript:

```
var ddlConsultantCompany = document.getElementById("ddlConsultantCompany");
```

I know I am triggering the javascript as I had set up a couple of alerts to tell me how far I have gotten in the process. I inspected the webpage itself and know that the ID for the dropdownlist is *ddlConsultantCompany*. Here are a few of the things that I have tried:

```
ddlConsultantCompany.readonly();
ddlConsultantCompany.enable(true);
```

I also looked up the actual guide from Telerik and haven't been able to get that to work either(Telerik tutorial[1](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/readonly)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#dropdownID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: That worked, but could you go into a bit of detail as to how?

Comment: I think the only way to make dropdown readonly is to make them disabled. Its similar to <select disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>